# How density dependent layouts work?

Tags: android, layout

How does the density dependent layouts work?

**For landscape orientation only:**

Two tablets -

One with mdpi density and 7inch screen size.
Other with tvdpi density and 7inch screen size.

**I placed the `layout1.xml` in folder `layout-large-land`.**

**The result: **

Tablet 1 with mdpi density working fine but Tablet 2 with tvdpi density layout disordered like shorter bitmap length and shorter margins for child layouts.

On account of getting this problem, I did the following change:

The `layout1.xml` now is in two different folders viz..

**`layout-large-land`. and `layout-large-land-tvdpi`.**

Now, Do I need to adjust (`bitmap length and shorter margins for child layouts`) manually for `layout1.xml` in `layout-large-land-tvdpi`  OR will android auto adjust and set the tvdpi pixels by just seeing that its in a folder `layout-large-land-tvdpi`?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is mostlikely using absolute pixels, while, for sake of compatibility among variety of devices you should use device independent pixels. Also to avoid ending with blurry images (like upscalled from `mdpi` to `tvdpi`) you shall consider having your assets made for certain densities. Anyway, this is quite elementary subject and well explained in android docs: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: The compatibility is well considered. The layout-large-land is independent of device pixels. It is the special case when I have tvdpi density for 7inch screen device and so I am using layout-large-land-tvdpi. Will it auto change the margins and height as I read in docs that mdpi is considered as base layout for any device. So layout for tvdpi will be auto adjusted accordingly.

Comment: `large` is kind of bucket for screens are at least 640dp x 480dp, but it still requires you to craft your layout files correctly

Comment: Ok that's about `large`. And what about density based layouts as mentioned in question: one for mdpi (layout-large-land) and the other for tvdpi (layout-large-land-tvdpi). Is that the same too as large in auto setting but with density?